# Oracle Apex modify generic ID

Tags: css, oracle-apex, apex

Is there a way to change the generic ID on Oracle Apex? I cannot use the id below for the other Modal page containing the said ID will we affected. My solution is to set a different id on this Session Timeout ui-id-2 Modal Page.

Also I am not sure why this code: span#ui-id-2{code..} works when applied on Page CSS inline, but when applied on Static Application Files .CSS it is not working.

Oracle v20.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can do it using jQuery, but it will work only in runtime

```
$("#ui-id-2").attr("id","newId");
```

And the thing with CSS maybe you need to add !important to override the class.

Comment: I have tried that. But the thing is, this generic ID were also available in all of Modal Pages. But what I want is only the Session Timeout modal pop up page it will be implemented. Is that possible?

Comment: I understood, what if you clone the template and change the ID as you desire? You can switch the default template for this new one